# How can I code using 5*5 structuring element Dilation in Aforge.net?

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

AForge.NET framework provides set of filters from mathematical morphology. All of the filters may be applied as using default structuring element, as using custom specified structuring element.

In Dilation the filter assigns maximum value of surrounding pixels to each pixel of the result image. Surrounding pixels, which should be processed, are specified by structuring element: 1 - to process the neighbor, -1 - to skip it.

The filter especially useful for binary image processing, where it allows to grow separate objects or join objects.

For processing image with 3x3 structuring element, there are different optimizations available, like Dilatation3x3 and BinaryDilatation3x3.

The filter accepts 8 and 16 bpp grayscale images and 24 and 48 bpp color images for processing.

This is the code for 3*3 structuring element:

```
Dilatation filter = new Dilatation( );
filter.Apply( image );
```

But I need to implement this code using 5*5 structuring element. How can I modify this code to 5*5 structuring element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know AForge.NET framework, but an erosion/dilation of dimensions 5x5 is equal to two erosions/dilations of dimensions 3x3. This is what is done in libraries supported hexagonal structuring elements.

So in your case, you simply apply twice the operation. According to your code, it would be:

```
Dilatation filter = new Dilatation( );
filter.Apply( image );
filter.Apply( image );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a Dilatation filter and pass it a custom structuring element as spec'd [here](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/aebf622a-7b2c-4fb7-bfa3-be74aef8d57a.htm). The structuring element you want is a 2 dimensional Int array with the following structure:

```
new short[5,5]{ 
{ 1,1,1,1,1 },
{ 1,1,1,1,1 },
{ 1,1,1,1,1 },
{ 1,1,1,1,1 },
{ 1,1,1,1,1 },
}
```